# Заполнить двумерный массив рандомными числами и вывести их сумму

Tags: c++

Дан двумерный массив 3х3, заполнить его через рандом и посчитать сумму всех элементов массива. То что я написал, на мой взгляд работает не правильно. Подскажите пожалуйста, где допущена ошибка?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "ctime"
using namespace std;


void main()
{
    int mas[3][3];
    int i, j, sum;

    srand(time(NULL));
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            mas[i][j] = 0 + rand();
            sum = sum + mas[i][j];

        }
    }

    cout << mas[i][j] << endl;
    cout << sum << endl;
    _getch();

}
```

Comment: Для отображения массива также нужен вложенный цикл...

Comment: "работает не правильно" ни о чём не говорит!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом код правильный. Вызывает вопрос  mas[i][j] = 0 + rand(); - зачем нужно прибавлять 0, если  mas[i][j] = rand() дает тот же результат. Для вывода массива используйте

```
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            cout << mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
       cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Ну, и выводить также можно по мере заполнения, вместе с подсчетом суммы (тем более, что вывод явно в познавательных целях, по условию задачи вроде не требуется)

Answer (score 1):

В коде есть неопределенное поведение.

Первое место:

```
        mas[i][j] = 0 + rand();
        sum = sum + mas[i][j];
```

Т.к. в зависимости от компилятора rand() может вернуть от 0 до 32767 (MSVC) или от 0 до 2147483647 (gcc, clang), то в строчке

```
sum = sum + mas[i][j];
```

может случится переполнение 9 раз. Можно объявить sum как 64 битный int

```
int64_t sum = 0;
```

Второе место:

```
cout << mas[i][j] << endl;
```

Фактически вы обращаетесь к ячейки mas[3][3], а это выход за границы массива, там может быть что угодно.

Comment: Еще можно сделать `sum` беззнаковым. Сумма, конечно, может быть математически не та, но от UB избавит.

Comment: Если int 4 байта, то не поможет: (2147483647-1) + (2147483647-1) + (2147483647-1) -> переполнение. Чтоб не зависить от компилятора, лучше так: mas[i][j] = (0 + rand()) & 0xFFFF;

Comment: беззнаковые числа не имеют переполнения, приводящего к UB. Там просто работает арифметика сложения по модулю.

Comment: Ну "sum", то будет не корректен...

Comment: ну, я об этом сразу же написал :)